# Send input type="file" form data via ajax post (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to send the post data from an input like this:

```
<input type="file" name="userFile" id="userFile"/>
```

?

I need to send it via ajax using $.post to a specified file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you search here first before asking?

Comment: Its not possible to send form/multipart data via ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without HTML5, this isnt possible, and the html5 solution won't work in all browsers without workarounds for browsers that don't support it.

The most cross-browser way to solve this is to not use ajax and to instead post to a hidden iframe.

Or use a plugin such as [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

Most if not all of the jQuery plugins that implement this use either flash or hidden iframes when the html5 method isn't supported.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [jquery.form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin....